# Which Google sheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have multiple columns (say columns A to E) which contain various values. Some values are present in more than one column. I'd like to know in which column(s) a specific value is present - something like this:

value1 - ColumnA, ColumnC
value2 - ColumnB
value3 - 0
etc.

Hope I'm being clear enough.

Which formula(s) can I use?

Comment: Welcome! Not sure what "value3 - 0" means. If `value3` exists, then it must be in at least one of the columns? And why are you only interested in the column? After all, it is possible to specify the exact position of the value - both the column and the row (cell address).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Try this:

```
={"Value","Cell(s)";
  SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A1:E20))),
  ArrayFormula(MAP(SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A1:E20))),
    LAMBDA(unival,TEXTJOIN(";",1,
      IF(unival=A1:E$20,
         ADDRESS(ROW(A1:E20),COLUMN(A1:E20),4)
         ,""))))) }
```